# Character axis gets messed up when I add the armature into it

Tags: unity, blender, fbx, import

So basically Ive been working on a walking animation in Blender, but theres a problem when I import it to Unity, the axis get inverted… The only thing that is messing it up is the armature that animates the character, if I only import the character itself the axis are normal, if I also import the armature, the axis get inverted...
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the specific symptoms of this inverted axis you're observing?

Comment: Added a picture

Comment: How does this contrast with what it should look like? How do the results of the animation differ from what you want?

Comment: The problem is with the code that gets messed up with this kind of orientation, I can edit it, but idk if keeping this axis orientation for the character is ok.